# Compare two file contents horizontally and vertically

Tags: text-processing, diff

I have two files:

File1 has the below contents:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10
```

File2 has the below contents:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

How can I find the difference between two files and print the odd number out and also to say from which file it is.

For example, in this case `9` only appears in File2, so how can I run a command and get output along the lines of

```
9 is only in File2
```

Comment: The difference between the files is that one contains numbers on a single row and the other contains numbers in a column, one per row.

Answer (score 2):

If you have clean formatting (space x newline), the easiest is to transform the line to the rows and just diff them, like this:

```
diff <( sed -e "s/ /\n/g" h.txt ) v.txt
```

Where `h.txt` is horizontal file and `v.txt` is vertical file

Comment: `<( cat v.txt )` is a UUOC.  Just use `v.txt` as the final argument.

Comment: @G-Man thanks. Fixed now. Sometimes I think too complicated

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use (G)AWK:

To find differences use AWK to convert file1.txt to line by line representation first, then pipe the result into diff:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS = " "} ; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' file1.txt | diff file2.txt -
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do it; here's `comm`.

First `printf` a header to interpret `comm`'s output -- giving the requested filenames -- then run `comm` on the sorted input, suppressing lines that exist in both files (`-3`). The two inputs to `comm` are process substitutions where I use don_crissti's `tr` suggestion to convert spaces in `File1` to newlines; then pass both files through `sort`, which `comm` requires.

```
printf "File1\tFile2\n"; comm -3  <(tr ' ' '\n' < File1 | sort)  <(sort File2)
```

---

### Sample run

Input File1:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11
```

Input File2:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Output:

```
$ printf "File1\tFile2\n"; comm -3 <(sed 's/ /\n/g' File1 |sort ) <(sort File2)
File1   File2
11
        9
```